How to render distortion around an object
I was trying to make a distortion effect around a moving object like this one

I'm not sure if there is a way to achieve this in blender or simply I have to use some editing software. Will appreciate any help.

I'm not sure what effect the picture shows, I guess a cone (result of shockwave) that refracts light ? You could simply play with a cone object and a refraction material. It would be easier to setup than post-processing it.
